# How to keep with the newest software updates without upgrading a distro?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, update-manager

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my notebook and I do not see any reason to upgrade to the latest 15.04 as I had some problems on my other system. Anyway I want to keep with the fresh software updates that come with a new LTS version. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Install from source.

Comment: Install from PPA.

Comment: The part "fresh software updates that come with a new LTS version" is confusing. 15.04 is regular release and *not* LTS release. Either: [1] This question is actually asking how 14.04 system can have packages that are available in 16.04 (which is "new LTS version", but not available yet), --or-- [2] how 14.04 system can have newer packages that are available in *any* newer releases 15.04, 15.10, etc. Should clarify this. Because answer could vary depending on what packages to upgrade.

Comment: @clearkimura sorry. It is about the continuous support of the latest software updates. Is there one way to keep the updates without upgrading to a new version, whether it is LTS or not? Thanks